# SAP UI 5 column data field edit and update

Tags: sapui5

How I can catch a particular column data and modify it?

e.g. 
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview

```html
<ObjectIdentifier title="{Name}" text="{ProductId}" class="sapMTableContentMargin" />
```

in this I want catch column data and how can update it

I get column data by

```js
var tab= this.getView().byId("idProductsTable");
col=tab.getColumns()[0];
tab.getColumns()[0].setProperty("visible",false);
```

Here I have to show/hide only column text="{ProductId}" on external button. How can I catch table -- > column ---- > ObjectIdentifier -- > text data property

Please help.

Comment: The table you linked is not even selectable?! Let me rephrase: You want to programmatically alter the data of a sap.m.Table?

Comment: yes here I have to show/hide only column text="{ProductId}" on external button. how can I catch table -- > column ---- > ObjectIdentifier -- > text data property

Comment: You shouldn't catch the table at all -- just bind the columns `visible` property to a boolean property in your model, and upon clicking the button toggle that model property.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :)
basically I just want child object of column for view hide/show functionality. there are 2 views in one view I have to hide Product id from column and in one view both product and product id are display. 
I am trying to access child byID but getting it as undefined.

console.log(" >> ",tab.getColumns()[0].byId("productID").getProperty("visible"));